# Можно ли в return array прописать условия?

Tags: php, opencart

```
if ($query->num_rows) {
            return array(
                'product_id'       => $query->row['product_id'],
                'name'             => $query->row['name'],
                'description'      => $query->row['description'],
                'meta_title'       => $query->row['meta_title'],
                'meta_description' => $query->row['meta_description'],
                'meta_keyword'     => $query->row['meta_keyword'],
                'tag'              => $query->row['tag'],
                'model'            => $query->row['model'],
                'sku'              => $query->row['sku'],
                'upc'              => $query->row['upc'],
                'ean'              => $query->row['ean'],
                'jan'              => $query->row['jan'],
                'isbn'             => $query->row['isbn'],
                'mpn'              => $query->row['mpn'],
                'location'         => $query->row['location'],
                'quantity'         => $query->row['quantity'],
                'stock_status'     => $query->row['stock_status'],
                'image'            => $query->row['image'],
                'manufacturer_id'  => $query->row['manufacturer_id'],
                'manufacturer'     => $query->row['manufacturer'],
                'price'            => ($query->row['discount'] ? $query->row['discount'] : $query->row['price']),
                'special'          => $query->row['special'],
                'reward'           => $query->row['reward'],
                'points'           => $query->row['points'],
                'tax_class_id'     => $query->row['tax_class_id'],
                'date_available'   => $query->row['date_available'],
                'weight'           => $query->row['weight'],
                'weight_class_id'  => $query->row['weight_class_id'],
                'length'           => $query->row['length'],
                'width'            => $query->row['width'],
                'height'           => $query->row['height'],
                'length_class_id'  => $query->row['length_class_id'],
                'subtract'         => $query->row['subtract'],
                'rating'           => round($query->row['rating']),
                'reviews'          => $query->row['reviews'] ? $query->row['reviews'] : 0,
                'minimum'          => $query->row['minimum'],
                'sort_order'       => $query->row['sort_order'],
                'status'           => $query->row['status'],
                'date_added'       => $query->row['date_added'],
                'date_modified'    => $query->row['date_modified'],
                'viewed'           => $query->row['viewed']
            );
```

Можно ли задать условие ? $omg = это jan количество скидок минус купленный товар этот по пользователю! isbn - % скидки

```
    if($omg > '0'){price' =>($query->row['discount'] ? $query->row['discount'] : $query->row['price']) * $product_query->row['isbn'])/100) * '$omg')}
else{'price' => ($query->row['discount'] ? $query->row['discount'] : $query->row['price']),}
```

Comment: Ну так проверьте: `if (что-то там выполняется) "одна цена" else "другая цена"`

Comment: Не знаете какой файл общий для товаров будет?

Answer (score 0):

Напишите условие перед return

```
if ($query->num_rows) {
if($omg > '0')
{
    $price = (((($query->row['discount'] ? $query->row['discount'] : $query->row['price']) * $product_query->row['isbn']) / 100) * $omg);
}
else
{
    $price = ($query->row['discount'] ? $query->row['discount'] : $query->row['price']);
}
return array(
    'product_id'       => $query->row['product_id'],
    'name'             => $query->row['name'],
    'description'      => $query->row['description'],
    'meta_title'       => $query->row['meta_title'],
    'meta_description' => $query->row['meta_description'],
    'meta_keyword'     => $query->row['meta_keyword'],
    'tag'              => $query->row['tag'],
    'model'            => $query->row['model'],
    'sku'              => $query->row['sku'],
    'upc'              => $query->row['upc'],
    'ean'              => $query->row['ean'],
    'jan'              => $query->row['jan'],
    'isbn'             => $query->row['isbn'],
    'mpn'              => $query->row['mpn'],
    'location'         => $query->row['location'],
    'quantity'         => $query->row['quantity'],
    'stock_status'     => $query->row['stock_status'],
    'image'            => $query->row['image'],
    'manufacturer_id'  => $query->row['manufacturer_id'],
    'manufacturer'     => $query->row['manufacturer'],
    'price'            => $price,
    'special'          => $query->row['special'],
    'reward'           => $query->row['reward'],
    'points'           => $query->row['points'],
    'tax_class_id'     => $query->row['tax_class_id'],
    'date_available'   => $query->row['date_available'],
    'weight'           => $query->row['weight'],
    'weight_class_id'  => $query->row['weight_class_id'],
    'length'           => $query->row['length'],
    'width'            => $query->row['width'],
    'height'           => $query->row['height'],
    'length_class_id'  => $query->row['length_class_id'],
    'subtract'         => $query->row['subtract'],
    'rating'           => round($query->row['rating']),
    'reviews'          => $query->row['reviews'] ? $query->row['reviews'] : 0,
    'minimum'          => $query->row['minimum'],
    'sort_order'       => $query->row['sort_order'],
    'status'           => $query->row['status'],
    'date_added'       => $query->row['date_added'],
    'date_modified'    => $query->row['date_modified'],
    'viewed'           => $query->row['viewed']
);
}
```

Можно конечно сразу и в массиве указать условие и все расчеты, но тогда код превратится в непонятную кашу.